# How can I understand c({x:10}).x?

Tags: javascript

The complete code is

```
    var b = 10,
    c = (
            20,
            function(x) {return x + 100},
            function() {return arguments[0]}
        );
a = b + c({x:10}).x  // => 20
```

How can I understand `c({x:10}).x` ...

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: You can post a question on stackoverflow titled "What does 'c({x:10}).x' do in this context?"

Answer (score 6):

First of all, let's rewrite the code so it's easier to read.

The construct `(x, y, z)` evaluates to the last item (`z`), so:

```
var b = 10, c = function() { return arguments[0] };
a = b + c({ x: 10 }).x  // => 20
```

Now, the `c` function just returns the first argument, which is kind of pointless here, so let's remove it:

```
var b = 10;
a = b + ({ x: 10 }).x  // => 20
```

The object literal `{ x: 10 }` is also useless here, since we just get its `x` property and then discard it, so:

```
var b = 10;
a = b + 10  // => 20
```

Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this:

The assignment:

```
c = (
        20,
        function(x) {return x + 100},
        function() {return arguments[0]}
    );
```

assigns the last expression in the parentheses to `c`. The first two expressions (`20` and `function(x) {return x + 100}`) are evaluated but not used in the assignment. This is an example of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator) in action: any sequence of expressions separated by commas has the value of the last expression.

So at that point, `c` is the function `function() {return arguments[0]}`.

Then, `c` is invoked with the argument `{x:10}` and it returns the object `{x:10}`. Then the `.x` extracts the `x` property, which has a value of 10. This is added to `b` (which also has the value of 10) to result in a value of 20 being assigned to `a`.

Simple!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, `a,b,c` returns `c`, so `c = function () {return arguments[0];}`,

`c({x:10})` returns `{x:10}`,

`c({x:10}).x` returns `10`

so `b+c` returns `20`